# pass data from one window to another (inside same QML file)

Tags: qt, qml

i got two `Windows` inside the same .qml file.

Window1 has a `textinput1` and a `button`, and when I press the `button`, i'd like to send the string value from that `textinput` to the `Window2` `textInput2`.

I'm new to Qt and QML, been reading a lot on `signals`, `Loaders`, `properties` and can't materialize this kind of transfer. Can anyone do a simple 10-line example of such transfer please?

```
 Window {

        id:window

        TextInput {
            id:text1
            text: "This value is needed in the second Window!"        
        }

        Button {
            onClicked: window2.open()
        }


    Window {
        id.window2

        function open(){
            visible = true
        }            
        Text {
            text: text1.text
        }        
    }
}
```

If I do this it gives me `ReferenceError: text1 is not defined`, how can I reference the `text1` from the first `Window`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to use signals in such case:

```
Window {
    id: window1
    title: "window 1"
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 600
    signal someSignal()

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Open window"
        onClicked: window1.someSignal()
    }

    Window {
        id: window2
        title: "window 2"
        width: 400
        height: 400
        // you can use this instead of Connections
        //Component.onCompleted: {
        //    window1.someSignal.connect(show);
        //}
    }

    Connections {
        target: window1
        onSomeSignal: {
            window2.show();
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is more ... how do you say? ... more imperative -)

Comment: This worked, thanks :) btw, `signal someSignal()` is a function? how could I put some variables in it so the `window2` can see that data?

Comment: [QML Signal and Handler Event System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#adding-signals-to-custom-qml-types)

Answer (score 1):

> i got two Windows inside the same .qml file.

If you did then your code will work. Since it doesn't work, I will assume each window is defined in its own qml file, and you only instantiate the two windows in the same qml file.

> If I do this it gives me ReferenceError: text1 is not defined, how can
>   I reference the text1 from the first Window?

You will have to be able to reference the window first, and it should provide an interface to reference the text.

Keep in mind that ideally `id`s should only be used to reference stuff in the same source. On rare occasions you could go further, and reference `id`s down the object tree, but only parents, and none of their out-of-line children, it will however work for in-line children that are given `id`s in that same source. Meaning that if `window2` is created inside `window` then you will be able to reference `window` from inside `window2`. But if both windows are siblings in another object, the `id` won't resolve.

```
Obj1
  Obj2
    Obj4
  Obj3
```

In this example object tree, `Obj1` will resolve from any of the objects. However, `Obj3` will not be able to resolve `Obj2` if the `id` is given inside `Obj2`, but will resolve if the `id` for `Obj2` is given inside `Obj1`. But there is no way to resolve `Obj4` from `Obj3`. because the `id` doesn't act like a property, you can't do `someId.someOtherId`, that's only possible for properties. You cannot do `somePropertyObject.someId` neither. You can only begin with either an `id` or a property, and continue only with sub-properties.

When the `id` is not applicable, can expose objects or properties either as properties or property aliases. The first is useful when you want to expose a whole object, the second when you want to expose a particular property of an object:

```
Item {      
  property Item innerItem: inner // gives you access to the "entire" inner object
  property alias innerWidth: inner.width // gives you access to a property of inner

  Item {
    id: inner
  }
}
```

You can also have aliases to aliases.

Comment: I literaly have only one .qml file and everything in it. So based on your last code snippet, i have a `Window2` inside parent `Window1` and I can't get a value from inside `Window1` to `Window2`. Your last code snippet suggests a reverse process.

Comment: As the first sentence stated, if `id:text1` is in the same source as `text: text1.text` then it will work. The actual object structure doesn't matter, all id's are accessible from the same source, excluding the `id`s objects inside `Component`s, which are only accessible internally for those components.

Comment: It may be useful to post your full code, or preferably a minimal self-contained example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Edited the code up in the question, it is visible now that the second `Window` is within the first, parent one.

Comment: @Romy - well that code works for me as expected, aside from the `id.window2` - it should be a `:` not a `.` However that won't give you `ReferenceError: text1 is not defined`, it will give you `QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:29 Expected token `:``